# Why are some rooms on the map filled in, and some not?

Tags: unepic

When I look at the map in [Unepic](http://www.unepicgame.com/), I can see all of the rooms I've been to in the past.  Some of them are filled in though, and some aren't.

What does this represent?

[image: Map screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filled-in rooms are rooms that you have fully lit, by lighting all of the torches in that room.  There are in-game challenges and awards associated with 'fully lighting' entire areas of the map (mines, sewers, etc), so you can use this to help you find torches you've missed.

This is where I am

[image: Empty Room]

There we go, all torches lit.

[image: All torches lit]

And now the room is filled in on the map

[image: Filled room]